# Private Content Provider shared among my apps only

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-sharing

I've googled enough, but couldn't find this case. I want to write a custom Content Provider that is shared/accessible to only specific apps.

I've this scenario:

- Have multiple apps on Google Play. Say A, B and C.
- Want to write a Content Provider, say Z that could only be accessed by A, B and C. I'm thinking to publish Content Provider 'Z' as its own apk.
- When Z is installed on device; A, B and C can access Z. If Z is not installed, then first app will direct to Google Play to install Z.

Now my question is:

Is it possible at all to write such Content Provider at all, which is only shared among specific apps? android:exported="false" makes it inaccessible by any other external app. android:grantUriPermissions="true" doesn't work when android:exported is set to false, and setting android:exported to true makes it public accessible.

Please feel free to share other solutions too, if they seem more appropriate to my requirements of sharing info among multiple apps.

Comment: No it cannot be selectively accessible to only certain apps. What google does instead - not  just with `ContentProviders` but everything else too -  is check the calling apps signature   and only permits its own apps access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> android:grantUriPermissions="true" doesn't work when android:exported is set to false

Yes, it does.

However, `android:grantUriPermissions` may not be relevant for your use case, particularly if Z is its own standalone app. Z would have to be the one calling into A/B/C using an `Intent` with the `FLAG_GRANT*` flag, and I am guessing that this would not fit your plan.

If, as I suspect, A/B/C need to access Z independently of Z telling them that it can be accessed and granting the `Uri`-specific permissions, the standard approach would be to use a custom `signature`-level `<permission>`. You would then defend export the provider and defend it with that permission using `android:permission` in the `<provider>`. The theory is that only your app suite can hold that permission, because only your app suite will be signed by that signing key and therefore have a signature match.

(I say "in theory" because there are [issues with this approach](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md))

Comment: can apps signed with same cert and have signature-permission share data seamlessly (without even using content provider)? Do you have any example to look at? Thanks !

Comment: @bianca: No. Signature-level permissions do not magically create new IPC protocols; they merely secure the ones that exist. `android:sharedUserId` allows apps signed with the same signing key to share a Linux user ID, allowing them to read/write each other's portion of internal storage directly. However, this is very fragile. In particular, if any of your apps have already shipped, this is no longer an option for you.